# How to put bootstrap 4 columns in each rows in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Here, I am trying to put 4 columns in each rows of boostrap row. But the problem is that it all the columns in one row.
Below is my code

```
@model IEnumerable<AlphaWeb.Model.Models.Team>
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-img">
                    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="~/AlphaAssets/images/team/@item.ImageName" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="social-icon">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="team-body">
                    <h3 class="name">@item.Name</h3>
                    <span class="designation">@item.Designation</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I dont understand... You want to have one row per item in your model? and then each row have four columns?

Comment: @Darkonekt No suppose we have 8 item then four item in first row and another  4 item in second row

Comment: in that case you have 2 choices: 1 count every four within your loop.  or 2 change your model so that it is composed of items with a property that holds a collection of four items

Comment: I tried you code in an empty page and it works well as 4 items in a line.Could you show your displayed image?Or do you check that bootstrap css styles have been applied correctly?(.row { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if i got you right you need create row for 4 columns and then again create row.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0)
    {
        @:</div><div class="row">
    }
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-img">
                    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="~/AlphaAssets/images/team/@Model[i].ImageName" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="social-icon">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="team-body">
                    <h3 class="name">@Model[i].Name</h3>
                    <span class="designation">@Model[i].Designation</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```